# Join 2 Mongo DB tables with Id and ObjectId

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

My Scenario : I need to join 2 below tables in Mongo DB and condition is

testScenarioId(table 1) = _id (table 2)

Table 1:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58516a6838fdb54d744ba070"),
    "_class" : "com.TestResults",
    "testScenarioId" : "581cef861892ad1eb7d124dd",
    "runId" : 314,
    "status" : "passed"
}
```

Table 2:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57f41cb9319ed34079df8a2d"),
    "environment" : "STAGE",
    "component" : "platform",
    "scenarioName" : "ABC-1234",

}
```

i am able to do if i am joining with same local field and foreign field but not on the above case.

Comment: It is not possible. https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-22781

Answer (score 1):

Mongodb does not support type coercion in $lookup. So field of type ObjectId can not be looked up with a string type foreign field.

What you need to do is while saving the testScenarioId, you need to store as objectId.

I tried using $type in aggregation but its not supported. So currently here is no way to do it directly in aggregation pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement join in 2 collections, then you will be insert "testScenarioId" in ObjectId form.

At that time,you have insert id in string form and "lookup" Aggregation does not support this form of Id.

Reason why ObjectId: when query finds Id from first table (table 1), they will get id in ObjectId form, and after then they will compare id with second table parameter "testScenarioId" which was store in string form, and they will not match and query return null data.